# Organic groups, group content types and pathauto

Tags: 7, organic-groups, path-aliases

In pathauto module settings I have

> localhost/[node:group_group]

for all group types. I have few group types: 
Ex Technology, Arts, Design etc and within each group type you can create as many groups as you want.

So when I create a group named google, the path looks like this :

> localhost/technologies/google

.

I want to have any article created within that group and to have a path like this

> localhost/[node:group_group]/[node:title]/[content-type]/[title]

Ex:

> localhost/technologies/google/article/some-article

How to achieve something like this?
I could not find any token replacement pattern for my use case in pathauto module. Is there some trick here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I tried:

```
[node:og-group-ref:url:relative]/[node:menu-link:parent]/[node:title]
```

Worked like a charm.

So, I guess that you should go with:

```
[node:og-group-ref:url:relative]/[node:content-type]/[node:title]
```

*Note:
Posted the answer since this was the first result on Google (for me), and no answer was given... Perhaps it will put someone else in the right direction faster.*

Answer (score 2):

`[node:og-group-ref]/[node:title]` is what worked for me.

Comment: Note that `[node:og-group-ref]` will result in a URL chunk based on the actual *name* of the group. This can differ from the group's URL alias if you configured a manual alias there. If you want the group's URL alias, the answer by @Marcus Farrington points into the right direction ...

Answer (score 0):

this isn't a complete answer as I only have one group type ("projects"), but within admin/config/search/path/patterns I use

```
projects/[node:group_audience]/[node:content-type]/[node:title]
```

for each of the different content types, unless I want the url to display a different term than that of the content type. I believe this would cover the

```
google/article/some-article
```

part of your string. Presumably you'd just put your

```
[node:group_group]
```

in place of my "projects," unless [node:group_group] produces "technology/google," in which case go with

`[node:group_group]/[node:content-type]/[node:title]`.

Comment: Thanks, however [node:group_group] is not recognizable when the path is for a group content type. That is, an article path in pathauto doesnot recognize [node:group_group]. And that is how it is suppose to be. I could hardcode something like you said technologies/[node:group_audience]/[node:content-type]/[node:title], but in that case I have to create article content type for each group type. And thats a bummer.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this worked:

1. Install sandbox module [`og_token`](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/pfrenssen/1315154).
2. Apply patch `og_token-og_7.2-1930132-1.patch` to `og_token`, as per Drupal issue [#1930132 comment 1](https://www.drupal.org/node/1930132#comment-7308024).
3. Optionally, if you want the tokens to use the group's URL alias rather than group title: in file `og_token.module`, exchange function `og_token_get_group_labels()` with this:

   ```
   function og_token_get_group_labels($nodes, $options) {
     $labels = array();
     $sanitize = !empty($options['sanitize']);

     foreach ($nodes as $group) {
       $label = drupal_get_path_alias('node/' . $group->nid);
       $labels[] = $sanitize ? check_plain($label) : $label;
     }
     return $labels;
   }
   ```
4. Set your pathauto pattern to:

   ```
   [node:og-group-audience:first]/[node:content-type]/[node:title]
   ```

This solution is based on [lahode's work](https://www.drupal.org/node/1088538#comment-7120394). It achieves the same effect as the [answer by @Marcus Farrington](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/52782/16305) to this very question, which for me does not work with the latest versions of modules `og`, `token` etc..

All these problems with OG tokens are discussed at length in [Drupal issue #1088538](https://www.drupal.org/node/1088538).